# How can I write a return type to restrict values based on keys defined in an enum and types defined in an interface?

Tags: typescript, types, enums, typescript-generics

I have the following enum defining a set of keys:

```
enum SymbolField {        
        Ticker = "Ticker",
        Feed = "Feed",
}
```

And the following interface defining types corresponding to each key in the above enum:

```
interface TypeBase {
        [SymbolField.Ticker]: string;
        [SymbolField.Feed]: number;
  }
```

How can I write a return type definition so that the method `doSomething` is only allowed to return an object with key/values that corresponds to the keys sent in in the fields array and value types defined in the TypeBase interface?

```
type MyReturnType = any; // to be written

type doSomething = (fields: SymbolField[])=> MyReturnType;
```

Example: `doSomething([SymbolField.Ticker, SymbolField.Feed])` should be allowed to return: `{ Ticker:'TSLA', Feed:19}` since the keys are the same as the ones sent in and the value types are the same as the ones defined in the TypeBase interface.

Comment: Are there really only two options, or is the actual list in `SymbolType` longer?

Comment: The actual list is indeed much longer, not fitting for a good short example.

Comment: I just thought it would be good to know that because I could see a solution, but it wouldn't be suited to lots of entries there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Making the type of the passed array generic and using a mapped type to construct the return type will lead to the correct result:

```
type DoSomething = <T extends SymbolField>(fields: T[]) => 
  { [K in T]: TypeBase[K] }

const doSomething: DoSomething = (fields) => {
    return null!
};

const result = doSomething([SymbolField.Ticker, SymbolField.Feed])
// const result: {
//     Ticker: string;
//     Feed: number;
// }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygnhARgewDYDECWxUBMoDeUxJxAUKaQCqYDGA1sAE5QC8UARDQ8xwDQVKxdMGD52HEWP5kAvmTKYQAF2YAzAIa1gUKnAAOwAEIaAzjoKChAbXhI0WHLgB03RkwC6ALiinlTJQBzAG4rSlsEFAxsPGcpXG8ocCRmUPkyZQMdABFkGGQIYGUACyC2KAAeKihgAA9VEFxTWEiHGNwAPgAKNXbTHyprDwBKNg7CKGsAaSglXUS9QxNzaY8odNpkED8oXDyCotKQQJ9c-MKSsvYevtHWcctSJiKwJhAksFRUAEI5UIVNttlFBnqZPsD2Htzocgl0IvZok5XHR3HwWgjHLF4iMyAB6XGkAB6AH4gA)

Comment: This looks promising, thanks, but is there any way the restriction can be built into the return type instead of the DoSomething method type?

Comment: @user10103655 - I am not sure what you mean. Can you show an example of how behaviour should differ?

Comment: @user10103655 You would need to inline the type, so it would be `const doSomething = <T extends SymbolField>(fields: T[]: { [K in T]: TypeBase[K] } => {` for the declaration.

Comment: @caTS This has been really useful but what if I need to store objects of this type internally somewhere? How can I type that object? Right now I can use inline typing to make the callers of the doSomething function correctly infer the return type but internally the doSomething functions stores away objects just with an "any" type for lack of alternatives.